# How to open activity where user was in android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to do like in android, For example If My user is on Activity D and session expired so I am sending to Activity A.

When I login there successfully from Activity A then I want to send user to Activity D, not Activity B, or C

What is the way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

On the onDestroy (or in onResume depending on you manifest configuration) of every activity you store its name to the shared preferences. So when the user times out the last activity there , is the user's last activity to interact before getting kicked out. This will be used when the user logs back in by restoring its name from the shared preferences.

Save the last activity's name:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("ActivityName", yourActivityName);
        editor.apply();
```

restore the last activity in your main:

```
String activityToResume = sharedPreferences.getString("ActivityName", "DefaultActivity");
            try {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(activityToResume);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
            }
```

Comment: There is some other good way to do this. I dont remember now.

Comment: If I call CLEAR_TOP then it will call all destroy method, not sure what it will save in activity name so this might not work

Comment: @NSharma save it in onCreate or in onResume then

Comment: instead of saving on `onDestroy`, you may do **save-preference** code in method of kick-off. It's expected that method of kick-off should be in one **parent activity.**